# Why is it bad to defragment an SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, defragment

I heard on the internet that defragmenting an SSD is quite harmful. I was wondering if it is true, and if so, why? I've already done it a few times and it didn't seems to be broken at all.

Comment: This has been answered in a previous post - http://superuser.com/questions/1594/why-cant-you-defragment-solid-state-drives

Comment: it is not bad all times: http://superuser.com/a/1009410/174557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike platter drives, SSD drives can only be written to a set number of times. By defragmenting you are shortening your drive's lifespan for very little gain.

Fragmented files don't affect the speed of a SSD drive in any noticeable way so there is no reason to defragment.

Comment: it is not bad all times: http://superuser.com/a/1009410/174557

Comment: The last part of this answer is not true any more. Modern SSDs often hit their I/O per second (IOPS) limit before they hit their bandwidth limit. The more fragments a file is in, other things being equal, the more I/Os it will take to read it.