# While using the "defrag /c" command in cmd, does Windows also defragment SSDs?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, batch, cmd.exe, defragment

While using the "defrag /c" command in cmd, does Windows also defragment an ssd? Defrag /c will defragment all hardrive in the system, however I am not sure if it includes SSDs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Comment: related questions: http://superuser.com/questions/1150641/should-i-defragment-my-ssd http://superuser.com/questions/1594/why-cant-you-defragment-solid-state-drives

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Relevant: http://www.outsidethebox.ms/why-windows-8-defragments-your-ssd-and-how-you-can-avoid-this/ and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2014/02/17/whats-new-in-defrag-for-windows-server-20122012r2/